# In R package Formattable, how to apply digits and conditional formatting at the same time?

Tags: html, r, formattable

I have the object TABLE_LIST which is a list that has tables (I can't provide the contents for privacy policies, sorry).

I first created the object TABLE_LIST (It is a list of data.frames 2x12)

```
TABLE_LIST=lapply(1:4, function(x) data.frame(rbind(total.ratio4[[x]][-(1)], total.ratio2[[x]][-(1)]), row.names=row))
```

The following code gives me red and green font colors based on the value on the cell, and it works like a charm:

```
formattable(TABLE_LIST[[1]], list(area(,-(c(5,10)))~formatter("span", style=x~style(color=ifelse(x>1,"red","green"))),area(,(c(5,10)))~formatter("span", style=x~style(color=ifelse(x>1,"green","red")))))
```

However, I need COLOR AND comma separated numbers. My failed attempt is:

```
formattable(TABLE_LIST[[1]], list(area(,-(c(5,10)))~formatter("span", style=x~style(color=ifelse(x>1,"red","green"))),area(,(c(5,10)))~formatter("span", style=x~style(color=ifelse(x>1,"green","red"),digits(x,2))),

area(1:2,1:10)~formatter("span",x~ style(digits(x,2)))))
```

This code works well, but erases the formatting of the color. I do not know what else to do.

I have to mention I cannot change the original data.frame without messing everything up. So I gotta make the changes on table_list or formattable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it. So I will share this small knowledge to people who may have the same problems as me:

```
formattable(TABLE_LIST[[1]], 
            list(
                area(,-(c(5,10)))~formatter("span",
                                            style=x~style(color=ifelse(x>1,"red","green")),
                                            x~style(digits(x,4))),
                area(,(c(5,10)))~formatter("span",
                                           style=x~style(color=ifelse(x>1,"green","red")),
                                           x~style(digits(x,4)))))
```

Basically, inside the same formatter, on the level of style, add a comma and `x~style`.